# SimpleSequentialChain extra field not allowed error for arg: input_variables and output_variables

Tags: python-3.x, langchain

I am new to Langchain trying out a SimpleSequentialChain, but i keep getting the error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\Langchain\main.py", line 40, in <module> parent_chain=SimpleSequentialChain( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\Langchain\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain\load\serializable.py", line 74, in __init__ super().__init__(**kwargs) File "pydantic\main.py", line 341, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__ pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for SimpleSequentialChain input_variables extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra) output_variables extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)`

Here is my code:

```
import os
from constants import openapi_key
# import streamlit as st
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import LLMChain, SimpleSequentialChain
# from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
# from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] =openapi_key

# st.title("Welcome to Langchain")
# input_text=st.text_input("Enter your text")

first_input_prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=['name'],
    template="Tell me about {name}"
)

second_input_prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=['person'],
    template="when was {person} born?"
)

llm = OpenAI(temperature=0.8)
llm_chain=LLMChain(
    llm=llm,
    prompt=first_input_prompt,
    verbose=True,
    output_key='person'
)

llm_chain2=LLMChain(
    llm=llm,
    prompt=second_input_prompt,
    verbose=True,
    output_key='dob'
)

parent_chain=SimpleSequentialChain(
    chains=[llm_chain,llm_chain2],
    input_variables=['name'],
    output_variables=['person','dob'],
    verbose=True
)


parent_chain({'name':"dhoni"})
```

I tried reading the documentation and am following the same. Also when looking at the arguments accepted by the class to be initialized i cant find the fields. Am I missing something or is the Documentation incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
parent_chain=SimpleSequentialChain(
chains=[llm_chain,llm_chain2],
input_variables=['name'],
output_variables=['person','dob'],
verbose=True
```

use:

```
parent_chain=SequentialChain(
chains=[llm_chain,llm_chain2],
input_variables=['name'],
output_variables=['person','dob'],
verbose=True
```

SimpleSequentialChain does not provide input_variables & output_variables

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please consider adding a reference to verify your answer.